# Are preperiodic points subgroup?

Tags: dynamical-systems

Suppose that $G$ is a group and $f$ a group endomomorphism of $G$. Let $H = \{g \in G \mid f^n(g) = f^m(g) \textrm{ for some positive integers } n,m \textrm{ with } n \neq m\}$ be the set of preperiodic points of $f$. Is $H$ a subgroup of $G$?

I know that if $f$ is injective or if $G$ is finite then this is true because in this case $H$ is the same as the set of periodic points $\{g \in G \mid f^n(g) = g \textrm{ for some positive integer } n\}$. But I can't seem to figure out whether it is true for other cases. I'd appreciate some help on this!

Comment: I didn't manage to answer the question, but if you take out the morphism requirement, it's false.

A counterexample I found was $f(z) = z^2 - 3$ defined on $\mathbb{Z}$.
Notice $\mathbb{Z}$ is an additive group generated by $1$. 
Now, $\{ \pm 1, \pm 2\} \subset Per(f)$ and $0, 4 \notin PrePer(f)$ since they both blow up. So $PrePer(f)$ cannot be a subgroup, since it is not even closed. 

I'll update this if I find the answer with the morphism requirement.